# SQL: INNER JOIN that only returns results if all rows in the right table meet conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table named `CONTACTS` and a table named `REPLIES`, so that a Contact has_many replies.

Table `REPLIES` has a column `user_id`, that can be NULL or have a value.

I would like to find all Contacts that have replies (so INNER JOIN), but only those contacts that **all** their replies have user_id being null (so if a Contact has 2 replies, one having user_id null and the other having user_id present, I want to exclude that contact).

Comment: you probably forgot to add the query you tried, the sample data and the expected results to have any chance of getting an answer

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Do you want to select contacts with no response replies, since they don't have any replies with a non-null user_id?

Comment: Voting to reopen.  The question is perfectly clear, except for one point that likely would not have been addressed by a MCRE anyway

Answer (score 0):

try to use left join

```
select * from CONTACTS C left join REPLIES R on C.user_id = R.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

A `COUNT` on a column doesn't count the NULL's.
So it can be used together with an `EXISTS`.

```
SELECT *
FROM contacts c
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM replies r 
  WHERE r.contact_id = c.contact_id
  GROUP BY r.contact_id
  HAVING COUNT(r.user_id) = 0
);
```

**Test test 1, 2, 3:**

> ```
> --
> -- Sample data
> --
> create table contacts
> (
>   contact_id int primary key auto_increment,
>   contact_name varchar(100)
> );
> create table users
> (
>   user_id int primary key auto_increment,
>   user_name varchar(100)
> );
> create table replies
> (
>   reply_id int primary key auto_increment,
>   reply_text varchar(124) not null,
>   contact_id int,
>   user_id int,
>   foreign key (contact_id) references contacts(contact_id),
>   foreign key (user_id) references users(user_id)
> );
> insert into contacts 
> (contact_name) values
> ('Jane'),('John'),('Jimmy');
> insert into users 
> (user_name) values
> ('Bubba'),('Bob'),('Mark');
> insert into replies
> (reply_text, contact_id, user_id) values
>   ('Hi Jane, how are you?', 1, null)
> , ('Jane, please answer me!', 1, null)
> , ('Jane, why did you request that restraining order?', 1, null)
> , ('John, lets grab a beer. Jane is ignoring me.', 2, 2)
> , ('Johnny dear. Bob is stalking me again. Do something about it!', 2, null)
> , ('John, could you get Jane''s number for me? Bob requested it.', 2, 1)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> select r.reply_id
> , c.contact_name
> , u.user_name
> , r.reply_text
> from replies r
> left join contacts c 
>   on c.contact_id = r.contact_id
> left join users u 
>   on u.user_id = r.user_id
> order by r.reply_id;
> ```
>
> ```
> reply_id | contact_name | user_name | reply_text                                                   
> -------: | :----------- | :-------- | :------------------------------------------------------------
>        1 | Jane         | null      | Hi Jane, how are you?                                        
>        2 | Jane         | null      | Jane, please answer me!                                      
>        3 | Jane         | null      | Jane, why did you request that restraining order?            
>        4 | John         | Bob       | John, lets grab a beer. Jane is ignoring me.                 
>        5 | John         | null      | Johnny dear. Bob is stalking me again. Do something about it!
>        6 | John         | Bubba     | John, could you get Jane's number for me? Bob requested it.
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM contacts c
> WHERE EXISTS
> (
>   SELECT 1
>   FROM replies r 
>   WHERE r.contact_id = c.contact_id
>   GROUP BY r.contact_id
>   HAVING COUNT(r.user_id) = 0
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> contact_id | contact_name
> ---------: | :-----------
>          1 | Jane
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=df9e4b79cdfeafe1f4b02a68f5b1ddad)*

But it can also be queried by using a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT c.contact_id, c.contact_name
, COUNT(*) AS total_replies
, COUNT(DISTINCT r.user_id) AS total_users
FROM contacts c
JOIN replies r 
  ON r.contact_id = c.contact_id
GROUP BY c.contact_id, c.contact_name
HAVING COUNT(r.user_id) = 0;
```